# Seemingly simple MDX calculation but using the same dimension twice with different variables

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

Table:

```
X             Y             wins  losses
Apples        Oranges       5     2
Apples        Limes         2     1 
Apples        Strawberries  3     3
Limes         Pears         5     4
Limes         Strawberries  6     8
Strawberries  Limes         2     3
Strawberries  Apples        1     5
```

I need to sum [X].Apples wins where Y = Strawberries and divide that by [X].Strawberries total losses. [Measures].[some_calculated_member] = 3 / (5 + 3)

An alternative would be to calculate it this way: 
SUM([X].Apples wins where Y = Strawberries / SUM([Y].Strawberries wins)

I'm not sure how to structure the MDX query to accomplish what I need:

```
SELECT
{ [Measures].[some_calculated_member] } ON 0,
{ [X].[Apples] } ON 1,
{ [X].[Strawberries] } ON 2,
{ [Y].[Strawberries] } ON 3
FROM [cube]
```

I've looked into using `AXIS` but I'm using Mondrian, which doesn't support `AXIS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with a calculated measure?

```
WITH 
Member [Measures].[Ratio] AS (
  [Measures].[wins.SUM],
  [X].[ALL].[AllMember].[Apples],
  [Y].[ALL].[AllMember].[Strawberries]
) / (
  [Measures].[losses.SUM],
  [Y].[ALL].[AllMember].[Strawberries]
) 
SELECT NON EMPTY {
  [Measures].[New Measure]
} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [SomeCube]
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Do you mind telling me for my own learning purposes why this didn't work? 

WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[Ratio] as (([X].[Apples], [Measures].[wins] ) / SUM({[Y].CurrentMember}, [Measures].[wins]))
SELECT 
    {[Y].[Y].Members} ON COLUMNS, 
    {[Measures].[Ratio]} ON ROWS
FROM 
    [cube]

Comment: Why do you do "SUM({[Y].CurrentMember}, [Measures].[wins])"? as it means you're filtering [Measures].[wins] to [Y].CurrentMember, while by default, [Y] is already on CurrentMember